# Windows Service can't connect to database - ConnectionString property has not been initialized. 

Tags: .net, windows-services, sqlconnection

I tried to build a SQLconnection from my C# based Windows service to my database.

> connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SQLConnection"];

I've already configured the app.config file and specified the `<connectionStrings>`. The Scheduler.exe.config is located in the scheduler installation folder.

> 2012-04-30+16:41:59|System.InvalidOperationException: The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.

What's the problem of my settings?

Comment: Edit your question to include the code concerning your SqlConnection.

Comment: @p.campbell here you go!

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to set your connection string to your SqlConnection, and use the `ConnectionStrings` collection from your web config. Here's an example:

```
  SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection();
  c.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySqlServer"].ConnectionString;
```

You're currently using the `AppSettings` collection, but you state that your value is in the `<connectionStrings>` node of your .config.